Error when cloning the remote azure repository: Unable to start process. Unable to associate job object with the process during process creation
I am getting the following error in Visual Studio 2022 (17.10.2) when I try to clone a project from an Azure repository.

The operating system is Windows 10 Enterprise, and ZScaler is also installed.
I tried to execute it as Administrator but i can not because my account is not Admin
Steps to Reproduce:

Open VS 2022 y choose "Clone a repository"


Enter the repo link


Error araises



Additional Information:

Git dropdown options are empty



git clone not works


Hi there, can you please specify your issue reproducing steps with some screen shots? As a possible workaround at the moment, was the git clone command working for you?

@AlvinZhao-MSFT I just added information, thanks!

Thanks for the response, which URL of the repo that you have used, HTTPS or SSH? Have your tried to clone a github public repo for a test, like git clone https://github.com/Azure-Samples/js-e2e-express-server? Was the issue reproducible with any git repo provider like github?

@AlvinZhao-MSFT I used HTTPS protocol URL and I tried with a public repo (GitHub) aswell but not work

What if you select to Clone a repo -> Click on Azure DevOps -> Login with your Azure DevOps account then search for the expected repo in the dropdown menu? On the other hand, please also try and reinstall git https://git-scm.com/downloads; then test with git clone.

As another possible workaround, you may also generate SSH key pairs -upload the public key to Azure DevOps -> run git clone <SSH_URL>. See the steps in this document.

@momiavive - Can you share the GitRepo which  you are trying to clone? Have you tried any other repo to make sure your 1st Repo is correct.

@Harshitha I can not share the git repository because it is a private repository for the organization I work for.
I tried with the public repos given by Alvin but it didn't work either.

Ok..Can you share any public repo which you tried to clone.

@Harshitha I tried with git clone https://github.com/Azure-Samples/js-e2e-express-server.

Does reinstall git or clone via SSH work for you? What is the error when you run the git clone in Command/PowerShell prompt?
